# Sumar valores de un array en php

Tags: php, array

quiero recorrer un array de objetos que traigo de la base de datos y quitarles los caracteres de moneda y los decimales para luego sumar todos esos valores del array, para ponerlos en contexto este es el array que obtengo de la consulta

```
Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [valor_abono] => $ 3.400.000,00
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [valor_abono] => $ 2.000.000,00
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [valor_abono] => $ 3.000.000,00
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [valor_abono] => $ 10.000.000,00
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [valor_abono] => $ 10.000.000,00
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [valor_abono] => $ 5.000.000,00
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [valor_abono] => $ 2.500.000,00
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [valor_abono] => $ 1.590.000,00
    )
```

)

quiero primero que todo limpiar el formato que tienen como el signo $ , el espacio en blanco, los puntos y la coma, para poder luego sumar todos estos valores, alguno podría ayudarme con esta solución, saludos

Hasta el momento tengo esto en código

```
//Variable que tiene la consulta de todos los valores
        $comparar_abonos_total = $this->_abonos->consultar_todos_valor_abonos_lote($_POST['id_lote']);
        $array = array();

        //variable que contiene todos los caracteres que quiero reemplazar
        $replace = array('$', ' ', '.', ',00');
        foreach ($comparar_abonos_total as $value) {
                array_push($array, str_replace($replace, '', $value->valor_abono));
        }
```

y esta es la salida al imprimir la variable `$array`

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  3400000
    [1] =>  2000000
    [2] =>  3000000
    [3] =>  10000000
    [4] =>  10000000
    [5] =>  5000000
    [6] =>  2500000
    [7] =>  1590000
)
```

lo que creo es que el espacio en blanco que hay antes de cada valor no lo quito del array de caracteres que quiero quitar

Comment: Edita por favor y muestranos que llevas al momento

Comment: No se entendió tu comentario final.

Comment: lo que quiero decir es que  mi array de opciones  llamado $replace no reemplaza el espacio en blanco por delante de los numeros del array para poder sumar los valores

Comment: al imprimir la suma de los valores con array_suma($array); su resultado es 0

Comment: La pregunta es, ¿por qué traes esos datos formateados si no los necesitas formateados? Espero que esos datos no existan así en la BD. Y, si es para sumarlos, ¿por qué no los sumas directamente en la consulta SQL? Espero que no haya un grave problema de diseño en tu tabla que te obligará constantemente a parchear ese error sobrecargando el código, el servidor y arriesgándote a manipular los datos una y otra vez.

Answer (score 0):

Coincido con @A.Cedano en que los importes deben guardarse sin formato en base de datos, para que puedas realizar operaciones directamente desde la consulta.

Con tu código actual usa [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php) para eliminar espacios alrededor del valor y [array_sum()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum) para sumar todos los valores:

```
    //Variable que tiene la consulta de todos los valores
    $comparar_abonos_total = $this->_abonos->consultar_todos_valor_abonos_lote($_POST['id_lote']);
    $array = array();

    //variable que contiene todos los caracteres que quiero reemplazar
    $replace = array('$', ' ', '.', ',00');
    foreach ($comparar_abonos_total as $value) {
        $array[] = trim(str_replace($replace, '', $value->valor_abono)));
    }
    // Sumar valores
    $suma = array_sum($array);
```

PHP suele ser flexible con el tipo de datos al realizar operaciones matemáticas, interpretando cadenas como números, pero siempre hay la posibilidad de errores y, de ser el caso, convendría usar [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.intval) para convertir a entero antes de agregar al arreglo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu consejo, es cierto que hice una mala practica al guardar esos datos de esa forma, en vez de guardar tipo numérico. de tanto voltear con la solución hice otra estructura y para mi dio resultado, solo debo mencionar que para poder quitar el valor de signo $ y el espacio lo que hice fue copiar directamente esos caracteres de la base de datos y de esta forma pude quitar los caracteres y volver entero los valores para poder sumar, ya les comparto mi solución en una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Primero hice una nueva función que recibe el string y hace el reemplazo de los caracteres que necesitaba eliminar.

```
function str_replaceChars($str)
{
    $array = array('$ ', '.');
    $signal = str_replace($array,"",$str);
            
    return $signal;
}
```

para luego llamarla y usarla de la siguiente forma:

```
//Variable que tiene la consulta de todos los valores
$comparar_abonos_total = $this->_abonos->consultar_todos_valor_abonos_lote($_POST['id_lote']);
$array = array();
//Se recorre esos valores para a cada uno aplicar la funcion str_replaceChar
foreach ($valor_abono as $value) {
    $v = $this->str_replaceChars($value);
    $array[] = (int) $v;
}
$suma_abonos = array_sum($array);
```